# tikz can not find the intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

Hello I do not understand why tikz can not find the intersection of the curve and the right?
thank you

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.015,yscale=0.01]

\draw[domain=0:500,samples=1000,variable=\x,name path=A] plot ({\x},{475.-712.*exp(-0.133e-2*\x*10)+238.*exp(-0.400e-2*\x*10)});
\draw[-latex] (0,0)coordinate(O)-- (500,0) node[above]{$t$};
\draw[-latex] (O) -- (0,500) node[right]{$\theta_s(t)$};

\draw[dashed,thick,name path=S100] (0,{475}) --  (500,{475});

\draw[dashed,thick,name path=S95] (0,{475*0.95}) --  (500,{475*0.95});
\path[name intersections={of=S95 and A,by=E}];


\draw (E) |- (O-|E);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

with the answer of  [TikZ doesn't find all intersections between plot and a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127400/tikz-doesnt-find-all-intersections-between-plot-and-a-line)

I Use smooth option and tikz find the intersection

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.015,yscale=0.01]

\draw[domain=0:500,samples=1000,variable=\x,name path=A,smooth] plot ({\x},{475.-712.*exp(-0.133e-2*\x*10)+238.*exp(-0.400e-2*\x*10)});
\draw[-latex] (0,0)coordinate(O)-- (500,0) node[above]{$t$};
\draw[-latex] (O) -- (0,500) node[right]{$\theta_s(t)$};

\draw[dashed,thick,name path=S100] (0,{475}) --  (500,{475});

\draw[dashed,thick,name path=S95] (0,{475*0.95}) --  (500,{475*0.95});
\path[name intersections={of=S95 and A,by=E}];

\draw (E) |- (O-|E);

\end{tikzpicture}
```